# Liouville theorem for elliptic equation with advection term

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

How can one prove that any $L^2$ solution of
$$ - \Delta \phi(x) + a(x) \cdot \nabla \phi(x)=0 \qquad \mbox{in } \mathbb R^N $$
is zero if  $a(x)$ is a divergence-free vector field such that
$\int |\nabla a|^2 dx < \infty$?   If the statement above is not true, under which additional assumption of $a$ and $\phi$ is it? For example, do we also need to assume additional decay for $a$ if $N\ge 2$?

A similar question has been asked in [A Liouville theorem involving an advection term](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186856/a-liouville-theorem-involving-an-advection-term)