# Liouville theorem for an elliptic equation with gradient perturbation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

How can I prove the following Liouville theorem for an elliptic equation with gradient perturbation?

> Let $u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R)$ be a smooth solution of
> $$ -\Delta u + v \cdot \nabla u = 0 \qquad \text{in } \mathbb R^n$$ where we assume
> $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla v|^2 dx \leq C$ and $\mathrm{div}v=0$ for some $C > 0$, then $u$ is constant.

Comment: I guess that $u$ is a function rather than a vector and that the conclusion should be $u=0$. Do you assume integrability only for $\nabla v$?

Comment: a related question   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186856/a-liouville-theorem-involving-an-advection-term/186991#186991